# ¿Como hacer un generador de codigos en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa en Visual Studio C# y quiero agregarle un generador de códigos ya sea de forma ascendente o de forma aleatoria. Espero y me ayuden. Gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Que dificultad te detiene? Publica tu código y resultados esperados para mejor ayudarte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual fue el problema que tuviste?

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Qué sería de forma ascendente? Ahí deberías definir qué tanto crece el número en cada generación. Podrías simplemente generar un aleatorio de 1 a 10, por ejemplo, y agregarlo al número anterior, pero claro, el resultado ya dista mucho de aleatorio.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar generar los Números aleatorios con el siguiente Método.

```
     static void EjemploRandom3()
     {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var justNumbers = new String(guid.ToString().Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            var seed = int.Parse(justNumbers.Substring(0, 4));
    
            var random = new Random(seed);
            var value = random.Next(0, 5);
   
            Console.WriteLine($"Iteración {i} - semilla {seed} - valor {value}");
        }
    }
```

Igual te dejo el siguiente enlace si gustas conocer mas acerca de la generacion de códigos aleatorios.[enlace a github](https://gist.github.com/Reflej0/d8407103d1a4eba8c0be24f63df24f1a#:%7E:text=Algoritmo%20en%20C%23%20para%20generar%20numeros%20aleatorios%20dentro%20de%20un%20rango%20definido.,-Numeros%20Aleatorios.cs&text=%2F%2F%20Crear%20objeto.,sistema%20para%20crear%20una%20semilla.&text=%2F%2F%20aleatorio%20entre%200%20y%205.) y este otro.- [Numeros Aleatorios](https://daniccardenas.com/crear-numeros-aleatorios-con-c-sharp/)

Espero te sirva a tu pregunta ya que no dejas nada claro.

Comment: Pero así estás creando un nuevo objeto `Random` en cada ciclo del `for`. No entiendo por qué hicieron eso en el segundo artículo. Incluso él mismo dice *"Si tienes que generar varios números aleatorios asegúrate de crear una única instancia de Random e ir llamando a Next cada vez"*. Con crear un `Random` fuera del bucle sin semilla alcanza y sobra, ya que toma el tiempo como semilla.

Comment: Algo a tomar en cuenta es, que si el proposito de los código que se desea generar son para claves o datos sencibles, nunca debe usar `Random` para este propósito, es mas recomendable usar `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider `,  para mas información al respecto, mire la [Clase KeyGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344255/8933039) para este propósito. (Debe Usar el Traductor si no sabe Inglés, para poder comprender mejor el contenido).

Answer (score 0):

Para generar un código aleatorio podemos hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
public string GenerateCode(int p_CodeLength)
{
    string result = ""; 
    // Nuestro patrón de caracteres para formar el código
    string pattern = "+-_#!?0123456789abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    // Creamos una instancia del generador de números aleatorios
    // cogemos como semilla los Ticks de reloj de esta forma nos 
    // aseguramos de no generar códigos con la misma semilla.
    Random myRndGenerator = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    // Procedemos a conformar el código
    for(int i=0; i < p_CodeLength; i++)
    {
        // Obtenemos un número aleatorio que se corresponde con una
        // posición dentro del pattern.
        int mIndex = myRndGenerator.Next(pattern.Length);
        // Vamos formando el código
        result += pattern[mIndex];
    }

    return result;
}
```

El método expuesto tiene varias ventajas. Ya la llamada del mismo me permite definir cómo de grande queremos generar el código. Y la forma en que lo hemos implementado nos permite a su vez definir un pattern o cadena de posibles caracteres para el código generado.

Una llamada para generar un código aleatorio de 8 caracteres se haría así:

```
string miCodigo = GenerateCode(8);
```

Mira que la instanciación del objeto Random lo hemos hecho ya con una semilla, que al haber elegido los Ticks de reloj de la hora actual forzamos que no se generen códigos con la misma semilla.

Comment: `new Random()` llama a `new Random(Environment.TickCount)`, no veo que haya beneficio en crear el objeto de esa forma. El único caso sería si por algun extraño motivo tienes que crear muchos objetos `Random` en un intervalo **muy** corto de tiempo y no quieres que generen los mismos números.

Comment: @Andrew, llevas razón. Antiguamente (y hablo de muy antiguo) el objeto random siempre generaba la misma secuencia y era necesario darle una semilla. Mira por donde he aprendido algo que no sabía, por eso incluía una semilla.

Comment: ¿Eso sucedía en .NET? Porque eso sí lo recuerdo de las épocas de Turbo C, donde debías llamar a `randomize()`, o bien `srand(time(NULL))` antes de llamar a `rand()`.